# Calculated value wont show in text field

Tags: objective-c, textfield, calculator

I am doing an app in xcode. Its intended to make a calculations where it divides the sliders value by 100 than multiplied with a text field (numberfield1) value which is determined by the user. Than the result is suppose to be shown in another text field (numberfield2). However the value is not displayed in the second text field. My question is what do I need to correct in my code to show the calculated result in my text field?

Here is my .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *counter;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberfield1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberfield2;

- (IBAction)changeLabel;
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;
```

Heres it my .m file:

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel {_counter.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%1.f"       
,_slider.value];}


- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
float x = [_counter.text floatValue];
float y = 100;
float calc_result = x / y;
float numberField1Float = [_numberfield1.text floatValue]; //converts the string in the text field to a float
float  calc_result2 = calc_result * numberField1Float;
self.numberfield2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", calc_result2];
}
```

Comment: 1st check your textfld is connected in interface builder or not?

Comment: are you sure IBActions fire properly at all? did you make a connection from interface builder to IBAction?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[self.numberfield2 setStringValue: 
    [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%0.1f", calc_result2]];
```